# How do I create dynamically loaded pages URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm noticing many websites with this AJAX loaded URL structure "#!", like twitter: (https://twitter.com/#!/apolinariosteps) but I couldn't find it documented (I didn't know what to search)

I'm not really sure if that is the solution (but I still wanna know how to do this), what I want is that when I load some content with Jquery, this cause a URL change somehow so I could share the page with the specific content loaded link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can search for "hash bang".  See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655634/hash-bang-and-google-seo

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Comment: This is **not** a technique to implement lightly. See [breaking the web with hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reload-less URL change exists natively in newer browsers through [browser history object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and can be easily polyfilled with [balupton's history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/).  The basic syntax will be `history.pushState(stateObject, title, URL)`.

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos The polyfill should work for most (I.e. IE6+) browsers without the HTML5 browser history object.